# GridView DataKeys enumeration null after sort function

Tags: c#

I sorted a GridView programtically using the code below:

```
grdCars.Sort(grdCars.Columns[3].ToString(), SortDirection.Ascending);
```

However when I went to get the DataKeys value after this using the code-below:

```
grdCars.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString()
```

It throws a `"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"` as the DataKeys "enumeration yielded no results" ie it was wiped after the sort.

Can anyone correct this please? Can I programtically sort the Gridview without removing the DataKeys enumeration?

Any suggestions/comments/code-samples much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The Data Source property is not part of the persisted state between round trip, that's why its value is lost.
if you are using Sorting event set a session variable set it to the sort direction and use it when you rebind your data-source.

```
protected void gridview_Sortingevent()
{
    // BIND Data with Gridview
    GridViewDataBind();

    DataTable dt = gridview.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

        Session["sessionsort"] = dt.DefaultView.Sort;
        gridview.DataSource = dt;
        gridview.DataBind();
    }
}
```

BInd to Grid view

```
 private void GridViewDataBind()
 {

    DataTable dt = GetDataTable();

    if (Session["sessionsort"] != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.
          dt.DefaultView.Sort = Session["sessionsort"].ToString();
    }
    gridview.DataSource = dt;
    gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the gridview.DataSource call is coming back as null. Any ideas?